# Create triangles as Links in header

Tags: html, css

I have a layout similar to this one on a website I am making. The way I'm doing it right now is basically just taking the layout as an image and putting it as a background with links above it. I now would like to be able to make the color of the triangle change on hover. How would I create this layout purely as a HTML and CSS element?
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIUCw.png) 
This is how the header is currently

```css
.back {
 max-width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
}
.About {
 position: absolute;
 color: #FFF;
 z-index: 1;
 left: 17%;
 top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<img class="back" style="background-color: #020105;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIUCw.png"/>
 <div class="About"><a href="">ABOUT</a></div>
```

Comment: If you post your html and css here and in a publicly editable editor like jsfiddle or codepen you will get more/better responses :)

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen is this better?

Comment: To get you started here's a [triangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) and there's a bunch of good css triangle tutorials that will pop up with a search.

Comment: Yea, that's definitely better :)  The more code you can show you did on your own the more inclined people will be to help you.

Comment: For a basic left triangle, with the editor, select 'bottom', scalene, left 200, right 0. You can adjust the sizes to make it fit. It gets a little more complicated if you're wanting to make them responsive.

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen For them to be responsive do you have any starting points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's junk but the best I could come up with on the quick..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/hL9ffjwy/

My way requires jQuery for computing the sizes and making it responsive. Adjust the jQuery height 'divided by #' to adjust the angle to what works best for you.

Probably a better way to do it with [`transform`](https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ntmDK)

```js
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  var containerWidth = $('.container').width();
  var triangleWidth = containerWidth / 2;
  var triangleHeight = containerWidth / 6;
  $('.triangle.left').css('borderWidth', triangleHeight + 'px 0 0 ' + triangleWidth + 'px');
  $('.triangle.right').css('borderWidth', triangleHeight + 'px ' + triangleWidth + 'px 0 0');
}).resize();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /*background-color: gray;*/
}
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: hsla(211, 100%, 50%, 1) transparent transparent transparent;
}
.triangle.left {

}
.triangle.right {

}
.link.left:hover ~ .triangle.left,
.link.right:hover ~ .triangle.right{
  border-color: hsla(342, 100%, 50%, 1) transparent transparent transparent;
}
.link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.link.left {
  left: 0;
}
.link.right {
  right: 0;
}
.link span {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-variant: small-caps;

}
.link.left span {
  top: 40%;  left: 70%;
  transform: translateY(-60%) translateX(-30%);
}
.link.right span {
  top: 40%;  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(-60%) translateX(-70%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="link left" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079168/"><span>Stack</span></a>
  <a class="link right" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079168/"><span>Question</span></a>
  <div class="triangle left" href="#"></div>
  <div class="triangle right" href="#"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with CSS, three identical triangles.

`triangle-base` is the base triangle with background black (if you remove the two triangles inside you could see it is a solid black triangle)

To achieve the triangle **border effect and the middle line effect** we need two identical triangles as left and right, but we shift those inner triangles up by 2px, and the inner left shift 1px left, the inner right shift 1px right.

Also as you can see `.inner-triangle-left` has `border-left` and `border-top` with width 0 and height 0 to make a left triangle, to understand more read here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Then you could see the border and center line. Change the background color to get a better idea what happened.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.triangle-base {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 60vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid black;
}

.inner-triangle-left {
  position: relative;
  top: -102px;
  left: calc(-40vw - 1px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 40vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid white;
}

.inner-triangle-right {
  position: relative;
  top: -202px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 60vw solid transparent;
  border-top: 100px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-base">
  <div class="inner-triangle-left"></div>
  <div class="inner-triangle-right"></div>
</div>
```